# How do you set bzip2 block size when using tar?

Tags: linux, backup, compression

I am using `tar` to backup a linux server to tape. I am using the `-j` option to compress the file with `bzip2`, however I can't see a way to adjust the block size options for bzip2 from tar. The default block size is 900,000 bytes which gives the best compression but is the slowest. I am not that bothered about the compression ratio, so am looking to make bzip2 run faster with a smaller block size.

Comment: Sidenote: Lately I've all but given up on bzip2. I use lzma (from the lzma, lzma-utils, or lzma-sdk package, name depends on your distribution.) It usually compresses the same or better than bzip2 given the same CPU time - and when it comes to decompression it simply blows bzip2 away.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
export BZIP=--fast
tar cjf foo.tar.bz2 foo
```

Or pipe the output of `tar` to `bzip2`.

Though you should note from the bzip2 man page:

```
    -1 (or --fast) to -9 (or --best)
              Set  the  block size to 100 k, 200 k ..  900 k when compressing.
              Has no effect when decompressing.  See MEMORY MANAGEMENT  below.
              The --fast and --best aliases are primarily for GNU gzip compat-
              ibility.  In particular, --fast  doesn't  make  things  signifi-
              cantly faster.  And --best merely selects the default behaviour.
```

Comment: how alternative you can use export BZIP=-9

Answer (score 4):

```
tar -cjf dir.tar.bz2 --options bzip2:compression-level=9 path/to/dir/
```

Comment: On my system (OSX El Capitan bsdtar 2.8.3) this is missing from the man page (although gzip:compression-level and xz:compression-level are listed), but testing it the option does work.

Comment: `tar: unrecognized option '--options'`

Answer (score 3):

### `bzip2` block sizes

`bzip2` has some block size options. From the manual page `bzip2(1)`:

```
-1 (or --fast) to -9 (or --best)
       Set the block size to 100 k, 200 k ..  900 k when compressing.
       Has no effect when decompressing. See MEMORY MANAGEMENT below.
       The --fast and --best aliases are primarily for GNU gzip
       compatibility. In particular, --fast doesn't make things
       significantly faster. And --best merely selects the default
       behaviour.
```

As you want faster compression with less regards to compression ratio, using `bzip2`, you seem to want the `-1` (or `--fast`) option.

### Setting `bzip2` block size when using `tar`

You can set `bzip2` block size when using `tar` in a couple of ways.

#### The UNlX way

My favorite way, the UNlX way, is one where you use every tool independently, and combine them through pipes.

```
$ tar --create [FILE...] | bzip2 -1 > [ARCHIVE].tar.bz2
```

You can read that as "create .tar with `tar` -> bzip it with `bzip2` -> write it to `[ARCHIVE].tar.bz2`".

#### Environment variable

It is also possible to set `bzip2` options through the environment variable `BZIP2`. From the manual page `bzip2(1)`:

```
bzip2 will read arguments from the environment variables BZIP2 and BZIP,
in that order, and will process them before any arguments read from the
command line. This gives a convenient way to supply default arguments.
```

So to use that with `tar`, you could for example do:

```
$ BZIP2=-1 tar --create --bzip2 --file [ARCHIVE].tar.bz2 [FILE...]
```

### Faster alternatives

`bzip2` uses a slow compression algorithm. If you are concerned about speed, you could investigate alternative algorithms, such as those used by `gzip` or `lzop`. Here is a nice article comparing compression tools: https://aliver.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/huge-unix-file-compresser-shootout-with-tons-of-datagraphs/

Comment: It looks like you may have the knowledge to provide good Answer here, but please consider reading [How do I write a good Answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) in our help center and then revise the Answer. Your Commands/Code/Settings may technically be the solution but  some explanation is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Send the `tar` output to `stdout` and then pipe it through `bzip2` separately:

```
% tar cvf - _file_ | bzip2 _opts_ > output.tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 2):

Its even easier:

```
% tar -cvf dir.tar path/to/dir/ && bzip2 -9 dir.tar
```

Comment: Using a temporary file means you need enough hard disk space, plus bandwidth for tar to write and bzip2 to read it. This may seem trivial for small amounts of data, but when the directory in question has several hundred gigabytes, it may become a real problem.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I know learned the deeper reason why `tar` has `-z` and `-j`. These options seemed rather convenient to me. But they can save the day.